# Get returned value from function called by getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

If `$.getJSON()` succeeds in getting the JSON data, then a function is called, as shown below. How do I catch the returned value `output`?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     // Do stuff with data if succeeds in getting the data
     return output;
     }
);
```

Comment: what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to use it to call another `$.getJSON()` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to invoke another function when the callback finishes, you should do that in the callback itself. It is invoked asynchronously and the result is not there on the next line. So:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     // Do stuff with data if succeeds in getting the data
     $.getJSON(data, function() { .. });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the callback is invoked asynchronously you can't deal with the returned value outside the callback.

Rather, inside the callback you need to process the "returned value" by writing it to a give or -- gasp! -- a global variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var outsideVar;
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     // Do stuff with data if succeeds in getting the data
     outsideVar = data;
     }
);
```

This way you write output into the "global" variable outsideVar (because it is declared outside), so you can access it from anywhere you want.

Comment: This won't behave as expected because of asynchronous execution. -1

Comment: It will work, if he reads the outsideVar later, after the getJSON was executed. This way he can access the data as often as he wants...

Comment: @winmwx Do you have the pice of code you are using? As I said before, the outside var will be filled, but you cannot read it right after calling $.getJSON, because it is asynchronous und will be filled later.

Comment: var outsideVar;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         // Do stuff with data if succeeds in getting the data
         outsideVar = data;
         }
    );
    console.log(outsideVar); // undefined

Comment: @winmwx Jep, and that is the problem. Let me show you how the program runs:
1. Defining var outsideVar
2. Starting the Ajax-Request. Because its asynchronous, the following code will be called immediately
3. console.log(outsideVar)
4. After a few milliseconds, the Ajax-Request finishes and the callback-function is beeing called, where outsideVar is being filled.

Comment: @winmwx I hope you now understand the problem. A solution would be to do all the logic, which has to be done after outsideVar is filled, inside the callback-function or calling another function from there. Another solution would be to do the ajax request synchronously. Please referr to the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for how to do this.

Comment: @Wulf Thanks! I'm trying not to do it synchronously since it keeps giving me warning that it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
the results of the call will be data


   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         // Do stuff with data if succeeds in getting the data
         retVal(data);
         }
    );

function retVal(myVal){
    //do stuff here, result is myVal
    alert(myVal);
}

edited, last code would not work in any way whatsoever.  this one will
```